# Getting last inserted records not only one record but multiple records

Tags: codeigniter

I am inserting ten to 11 records at a time through a textarea and I want them to show only those records not all other records.
I am using codeigniter. so I need a query in codeigniter.

```
$this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('try2check_cardinfo');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->order_by("id","DESC");
    $q =$this->db->get();
    echo "<pre>";
    $r = $q->result_array();
    $iddd = $r[0]['id'];
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("try2check_cardinfo");
   // $this->db->limit(3);
    $this->db->order_by("id","desc");

    $this->db->where('id >',$iddd);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
```

Comment: Please add your code snippet, and define your issue a bit more clearly. What defines "last inserted"? Is this in a insert iteration, or maybe time based? Either way you are going to want to store "last inserted" in a collection of some sort (array/list, object, map/dictionary, linked list, etc.).

Comment: where are your controller and model code, you only want the id of the 10 or 11 inserted every time?

Comment: I think you want to insert a batch of 10-11 records at a time and want to get back all inserted data of those 10-11 records.